# Ubuntu Gnome Error after updating to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, login, 17.10

after updating ubuntu gnome, I get a black screen with an error window every time I log in. I can just click ok and continue, but after a month or so of ignoring it I figured I should fix it. Anybody able to help me?

The error window looks like this:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:

Locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

The file contains these lines:

> ```
> # /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
> # and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
>
> if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
>   if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
>     # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
>     # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
>     if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
>       . /etc/bash.bashrc
>     fi
>   else
>     if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
>       PS1='# '
>     else
>       PS1='$ '
>     fi
>   fi
> fi
>
> if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
>   for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
>     if [ -r $i ]; then
>       . $i
>     fi
>   done
>   unset i
> fi
> ```

Comment: have you looked at `etc/profile` to see what the line is pointing to? can  you add to your post the contents of `etc/profile` .. just checked my profile and I don't see LC_ALL so it may be something you have installed that is setting that "path"   I looked up LC_ALL and found it has something to do with It forces applications to use the default language for output and probably not really necessary.. you probably can get away with commenting out that line in the file by adding a # before it .. but again .. it would be best if we could see the file and see if we can see an error in the line.

Comment: hmm ok that's odd ... the LC_ALL isn't even listed. I expected to see something like `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` or something like that .....ok it also looks in `/etc/profile.d` .. check `/etc/profile.d` folder and see if there are any files in there and if any of those files list the LC_ALL line.  if you still don't see it  check your `~/.profile` and see if LC_ALL is listed in there. I found something close in a file called `cedilla-portuguese.sh` that says `export LC_CTYPE="${LC_IDENTIFICATION%.*}.UTF-8"` but nothing that says `LC_ALL=` sorry, im just guessing, im not real familiar with this error

Comment: I have a suspicion that  something like `export LC_ALL="${LC_IDENTIFICATION%.*}.UTF-8"` is somewhere and not "set" right or is not getting the information needed from `${LC_IDENTIFICATION%` so you are getting that error and since it repeats it may be in there twice or in two different files in the profiles.d ... again .. guessing :(

Comment: All I found was in /etc/profile.d/vte-2.29.sh in wich there is:

      # This is important to make sure string manipulation is handled
      # byte-by-byte.
      LC_ALL=C
      str="$1"
      while [ -n "$str" ]; do
        safe="${str%%[!a-zA-Z0-9/:_\.\-\!\'\(\)~]*}"
        printf "%s" "$safe"
        str="${str#"$safe"}"
        if [ -n "$str" ]; then
          printf "%%%02X" "'$str"
          str="${str#?}"
        fi
      done
    )

Comment: that could be the offending file ..Again .. Im not saying you don't need it but ... I don't know for sure .. but you could just rename the file `sudo mv /etc/profile.d/vte-2.29.sh /etc/profile.d/vte-2.29.sh~` then try what you were doing to get that error and see if it is gone .. if so .. that's the culprit but ... you will have to find out more about it because again .. I don't know what its for or if it will cause issues down the road .. if it doesn't work or causes problems just move the file back `sudo mv /etc/profile.d/vte-2.29.sh~ /etc/profile.d/vte-2.29.sh` you may have to reboot